# Ubuntu 16.04 does not shut down

Tags: grub2, shutdown, gnome-terminal

I am new to Ubuntu. I have a Surface Pro 4 and use Ubuntu 16.04.

When I try to shut down Ubuntu whether from GUI or terminal using `sudo shutdown`, it goes to a page with the Ubuntu logo and some dots below it and it stays there. I have tried to remove the grub `quiet splash` and replace it with `quiet splash acpi=force`, but it didn't work. What should I do?

Comment: Is there any error when the computer is shutting down. Try to push an up or down key while it is shutting down to hide the logo and see if there is an error message.

Comment: "I have tried the grub "quiet splash" removing and replacing by "quiet splash acpi=force". but it did't work."  Did you  afterwards  "sudo update-grub".

Comment: You should be able to see the shutdown messages by pressing the escape key; this should give you (and us) some hints about the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, try turning off your wifi then do the normal power off. This is the only thing that works for me. I tried the sudo poweroff that worked sometimes but turning off the wifi has worked constantly. Seems to be an issue with wifi driver in 16.04 and 18.04.